# Tag mismatch error when using java web service WSDL with gsoap C client

Tags: java, iphone, web-services, using

I have created C client for the java Axis 1.4 Web service WSDL, using wsdl2h and soapcpp2 tool of gsoap 2.7.17.

I'm using these soap client in my iphone application. I'm able to compile the application successfully.

But, when I try to call a function of from the client file, it returns nil value in the response structure, but return code of the function call is SOAP_OK.

I tried debugging the soap files and have found that while fetching the data from server, there is some mismatch of tags, and hence, the client ignores the response and returns nil.

The standalone Web Service running on the same machine on Tomcat server.

So, can anybody help, what could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to dump the xml being received at the server.  It sounds like whatever stubs were generated for your c client aren't complete.   I've got zero experience with C clients, but depending on how much difference there is between the xml you're sending and what's being expected it might be easy, or well nigh impossible to fix.

Axis 1.4 can generate pretty ugly xml for certain java objects.  Depending on what you can control, you might have a faster time fiddling with the server code so that the wsdl axis generates parses better with your C tools.